# phpmailer not redirecting to page

Tags: php, phpmailer, email

I am making a mail sending module on user approvals. The mail is being sent to multiple users on the checkbox values. The problem is once I am using the given code it sends mail to all the checked users and redirects to the page given but as a blank page.

Now when I remove `set_time_limit(120);` few users are being left and mail is not sent to them even after checking all the users in list and the page is being redirected successfully.

Here is my code, please let me know rectification into this. This will be highly appreciated.

```
set_time_limit(120);              
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$subject = "Welcome mail";
$content ="AAFM";
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Timeout = 120;  
$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;   
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Port     = 465;  
$mail->Username = "xyz@xyz.com";
$mail->Password = "xyz";
$mail->Host     = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom("xyz@xyz.com", "xyz");
$mail->AddAddress($row['email']);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($content);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
if(!$mail->Send()) 
    echo "Problem sending mail.";
else
  echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Candidates approval successful. Thankyou')
    window.location.href='reportApprovalUser.php';
    </SCRIPT>"); 
$mail->SmtpClose();
```

I have subsequently changed the time_limit variable in `phpmailer` Class too as 120.

Basically when mail is sent to all the listed users, the redirection shows a blank page and when redirection shows the actual page the list still has few users left even on selecting all for approval/mailing.

Comment: Do you get the success alert...?

Comment: @GyandeepSharma Thanks for the concern. Yes I am getting the alert box. But when I click on OK the page keeps loading for a while and gives out a blank redirected page.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. Actually headers were not being sent due to whitespaces. Added `ob_start()` and its functional.